# How can load a cocos2d scene from view controller class?

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, cocos2d-iphone, iad, ccscene

1)I made a game using cocos2d-iphone v3.

2)I integrated a fullscreen advertisement.

3)I want to load a cocos2d scene, when user closes ad, but it doesn't work(I imported cocos2d framework).There is just a black screen after advertisement disappears with animation. "interstitialAdDidFINISH" appears in the output, so most likely, that last line is wrong.

```
-(void)interstitialAdActionDidFinish:(ADInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd {
    interstitial = nil;
    //    [interstitialAd release];
    // [ADInterstitialAd release];
    requestingAd = NO;
    NSLog(@"interstitialAdDidFINISH");
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCBReader loadAsScene:@"MainScene"]];

}
```

I guess, that I can't load a cocos2d scene from UIViewController class so easy.....
How can I do this?

EDIT: So ? It's not nil

```
 if ( [CCDirector sharedDirector].view != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Hey there");
    }
```

EDIT 2: I found out, that `[CCDirector sharedDirector]];` is a ViewController too. 
I tried something like this . The game crashes, after iAd finished.

```
    [self addChildViewController:[CCDirector sharedDirector]];
    [self presentModalViewController:[CCDirector sharedDirector] animated:NO];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCBReader loadAsScene:@"MainScene"]];
```

Comment: "doesn't seem to work" is not a problem description. Describe what is happening and what makes you think it only "seems" not to work (does it or does it not?). Did you verify that the code runs?

Comment: #LearnCocos2D I edited my question.

Comment: But the cocos2d part before the interstitial works fine? Do you do anything to stop CCDirector or deallocate its view? Check if [CCDirector sharedDirector].view is still a valid reference and CCDirector running its visit method frequently.

Comment: #LearnCocos2D Yes,it works fine. I use this line [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause]; when game over window appears, but I always resume game in didLoad. I tried to remove that line - there is just no difference. I don't deallocate it. I don't know how to check both, but I tried to guess what you mean(in the edited question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'v found solution. May be helpfull for others.

First, that's, how I present iad view controller from the MainScene

```
  *ViewControllerAdEx= [[ ViewControllerAd alloc] init]; // making an instance of iad class
  [[CCDirector sharedDirector] presentModalViewController:ViewControllerAdEx animated:YES]; 
  [ViewControllerAdEx showFullScreenAd]; // caling a method from class
```

In the iad class, when iad finishes work:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
     [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCBReader loadAsScene:@"MainScene"]];
    }];
```